# HTML Viewport Size Issue (100vw ≠ 100% of width)

Tags: html, css

In the following piece of code, I have attempted to make the width of a picture (a red square) equal to that of my — up to date — browser's viewport. However, the size of said picture is far from the latter's (as can be seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdtsB.jpg)). The picture is 1560px high and 1560px wide.

I've tried every potential solution I could find online, including using the <picture> tag with the *sizes* attribute or trying to change the picture's height with *vh* instead, and nothing worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="bar.jpg" width="100vw" alt="bar">
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this sizing issue while keeping the width relative to the viewport (and therefore not using a fix such as *width: 100%;*)?

Comment: Try `style="width:100vw"` instead of `width="100vw"`

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't tried that yet. It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<img>` width attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) is always unit-less, and refers to pixels.

> **width**: The intrinsic width of the image in pixels.

To apply a width with `vw` units, you must use CSS.

```
<style>
    .full-width {
        width: 100vw;
    }
</style>
<img src="bar.jpg" class='full-width' alt="bar">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the style property, `style="width:100vw"`, not the [width attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img). The width attribute is always in pixels, so `width="100vw"` is translated into `width="100px"`